# Insert and retrieve multiple values in one filed from SQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL table called "Contact List" which has three columns:

> Name | Phone | Email

One person can have more than one e-mail (each per row).

Let's say Person name is John and has three e-mails and I have to pull out all three e-mails.

I want to list all e-mails that belong one person by his name. What SQL query should I use?

Comment: I re-format your question and changed some words to be more clearly. The more clearly question will have more chance to read and understand in order to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert all the eMail IDs of that person in a single `eMail` column - separate them with comma, make sure the length of `eMail` field is wide enough to accommodate a couple of eMail IDs and you're good to go.

If you are okay with storing different eMail IDs of the same person in different rows, but want a the output with all the eMail IDs 
 listed against the name a.k.a.

```
|John | john@abc.com,john@xyz.com...
```

you need to use **[Group Concat](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)**

Let us say you have this dataset where John exists with two different eMail IDs:[image]

To get the result set as shown below, use a similar query (as shown in the snippet)[image]

here, **john** exists with multiple eMail IDs. Using *group_concat* lists all of them against one.

Comment: Thank  you for your response.can you give me more detail?

Comment: Sure. But can you tell me which use-case you need? Do you want to insert the data or you want to retrieve the data in the format of `John` example given above?

Comment: @CoskunOlcucu I've added the snippets. Hope that answers your concern :)

Comment: I want  both to insert  and retrieve data given example.

Comment: I am using C#  for this mini project.

Comment: I have name ,phone number and e-mail columns on my database table.

Comment: I've mentioned in the first para on how to insert multiple eMail values. On how to retrieve all the eMail values against a single person, use to query with *group_concat*, as is written in the second snippet.

Comment: Do you think it is not weird that putting same person record for different e-mails

Comment: No. That depends on how you sync your data. If you have an app that syncs the user eMails in your database- it would insert eMail1 when it syncs for the first time. If user creates another eMail2 at a later point, another row would be created for the user with different eMail_ID. Now while retrieving the data, it would make little sense to get multiple rows of the same user having different eMails.

Comment: I have other columns on my database like address and phone number,so every time I have to store same number and address for the sake of different emails.it wouldn't be weird ,right?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to solve this without any ugly hacks, you need to add at least one additional table. This table contains an e-mail address and the ID of the corresponding contact list entry (or whatever the primary key is).

At the moment, your table looks approximately like this

```
ContactList(Name, Phone, Email)
```

You insert values like this

```
INSERT INTO ContactList (Name, Phone, Email) VALUES ('John Doe', '0000000', 'john@example.com')
```

You retrieve an email address for a contact with a certain name like this

```
SELECT Email FROM ContactList WHERE Name LIKE 'John Doe'
```

What you have to do in order to store multiple addresses per contact, is to split this table into two parts.

```
ContactList(Name, Phone)
Emails(Name, Email)
```

Note: This is the minimal adaption to your database design that would work. I would not recommend to actually use this.

This would be a better design:

```
Person(ID, Firstname, Surname)
Phonenumbers(PersonID, Phonenumber)
Emails(PersonID, Email)
```

You can now insert entries without having to specify a phone number or e-mail address. Furthermore, both parts of the name (assuming that specific naming model fits your locale) can now be addressed independently. There can also be multiple phone numbers and email addresses per person now.

Now you have to insert people and email addresses/phone numbers on their own.

```
INSERT INTO Person (ID, Firstname, Surname) VALUES (1, 'John', 'Doe')
```

Afterwards, you can add phone numbers and email addresses like this

```
INSERT INTO Emails (PersonID, Email) VALUES (1, 'john@example.com')
```

and

```
INSERT INTO Phonenumbers (PersonID, Phonenumber) VALUES (1, '00000000')
```

If there are multiple e-mail addresses or phone numbers, simply repeat the last two examples as often as necessary.

The easiest way to get that data into you application would be to use multiple queries. An example approach would look like this:

First, you have to get a list of all the individuals in your database

```
SELECT ID, Firstname, Surname FROM Person
```

Then, for each person, you can get the list of all email addresses belonging to that person (example for ID 1)

```
SELECT EMail FROM Emails WHERE PersonID=1
```

You can get a person's phone numbers with the same approach. Once you understand how all of this works, you can try more advanced features like JOIN, GROUP BY or AUTO_INCREMENT.

If, however, changing the database layout is not an option, you can also write all email addresses into the existing email column using a delimiter of your choice (e.g. comma or semicolon). Assuming you are using some form of programming language to process the result data of the query, you can simply use a string split to retrieve the individual addresses.

Comment: I create a contact list web form using Microsoft Visual Studio.I am able to insert new person with name ,e-mail and phone number.only issue is what if person has more than one e-mail addresses.

Comment: I see, so you do have control over the database design. I will expand my answer to explain how to solve this issue by adapting the database design.

Comment: Thank you.I am waiting for your response

Comment: I have added a rather detailed explanation of the general approach. If you want to know more about the ideas behind this, I suggest you read about database normalization, primary/foreign keys and database relationship types.

Answer (score 0):

The relation between Person and Email in this situation is 1 to n. Therefore you can build another table that keeps emails for people with a foreign key that points to Person. Therefore we have this structure :

Table1 : TblPerson => Fields : Id (Auto increment Integer), Name , Phone

Table2 : TblEmails => Fields : Id (Auto increment Integer), PersonId , Email

PersonId is a foreign key and its value come from TblPerson.
When you want to retrieve data, you can make a join between these 2 tables :

```
Select P.Name , E.Email
from TblPerson P left join TblEmails E 
on (P.Id = E.PersonId)
```

But this structure shows repetitive Persons , i.e. if a person has 3 emails , this query returns 3 records for this person.
To avoid this problem , you can select all emails of one Person as a comma delimited string :

```
SELECT P.Name , GROUP_CONCAT(E.Email) as Emails
from TblPerson P left join TblEmails E
on (P.Id = E.PersonId)
GROUP BY Name ;
```

Result of this query shows emails of each person as comma delimited string in the same row.

Comment: I will try your suggestion.Thank you very much for your explanation.

Comment: I have other columns on my database like address and phone number,so every time I have to store same number and address for the sake of different emails.it wouldn't be weird ,right?

Comment: I created this web form using Microsoft Visual Studio.my form has save,delete,and reset button.when I hit save button I can insert new person to my database table,so how to insert new e-mail from that perspective.I mean let's say person john has an person Id is "1" when I add john's other email.how to put his foreign key to the email table.

Comment: This 1 to n relationship come in forms usually as Master-Detail Forms, i.e. there is a Master Table (TblPerson) and Detail table (TblEmails ). A possibility is to have 2 Grids in a page that contains a master Grid and under that Detail Grid. You have PersonId for master Grid .Another possibility is to have 2 Page for this 2 Tables or Entities. When you call second page, pass you PersonID. The second solution is better , because of SOLID standard.

Comment: No problem with extra Fields. If these Fields are unique for each Person you can define Fields in TblPerson and if are unique for each Email you can insert in TblEmails.

Comment: You're welcome.I hope this information will be helpful to you.